# Groupby in pure python

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by

I need some sql like functionality preferably with pure python but not panda. My requirement is to get the tag which length is just less than the max length.

Step 1: Get the max count of / in second column.

Step 2: Return the tag whose count of / in second column is one less than the one from step 1.

**My List is:**

```
['MYDATA_FILE_XT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW_STATUS', '/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS', 'string']
['XX', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_CURRENCY_CODE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE', 'string']
['YY', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_EXCESS_AMOUNT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT', 'string']
['LM', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW_USD_EQUIVALENT', '/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT', 'string']
```

**Expected Output:**
['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW'] ['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW']

Comment: You can replicate `pandas`-like functions with `itertools.groupby` after sorting. There are lots of similar examples. Would this be an acceptable method?

Comment: I am looking for a pure python solution. However how to do that using pandas?

Comment: @SimpleOne What is "pure python"? why is `itertools.groupby` not "pure python" ?

Comment: `itertools` is as pythonic as it gets. It is not quite pure Python (lots of C implementation under the hood), but the documentation contains an (almost) equivalent Python implementation for most functions ([`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) included), if you insist on it being functionally the same but slower.

Comment: I am new to python. Can you guys pls give a code block to the said problem.

Comment: @SimpleOne https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: @SimpleOne, Since you are new to Python: my advice is to lookup `itertools.groupby` (there are hundreds of examples on SO & elsewhere), *try and implement* a solution yourself. If & when you get stuck, come back and show what you've done / why you got stuck. That way, not only will you learn more, but other users might find the Q&A helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a set of (unique) paths
groups = set([line[1] for line in data])

# group tags as list per path
groupedTags = {}
for group in groups:
    groupedTags[group] = []

for line in data:
    groupedTags[line[1]].append(line[0])

# save the second longest tag for each group in output
output = []
for group in groups:
    if len(groupedTags[group]) < 2:
        output.append(groupedTags[group][0]) # if there is only one tag
    else:
        output.append(sorted(groupedTags[group], key = len)[-2])
```

Comment: Thanks Niklas. Seems my query has an issue. I should rephrase it: Step1: Group by second column. Step 2: get the tag which length is just less than the max length of that group

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you privide a short example illustrating the output of these two steps?

Comment: Step1: Group by. This should return   ['/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS']  [/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE]  [/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/EXCESS_AMOUNT] [/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/USD_EQUIVALENT]        Step 2: Get the tag where length of tag is just less than the max of each group. For group  [/MYDATA/FILE/XV/ROW/CURRENCY_CODE] should return   ['MYDATA_FILE_XV_ROW'] .similarly for group [/MYDATA/FILE/XT/ROW/STATUS]   it should return  ['MYDATA_FILE_XT_ROW']  ..and so on

Comment: Looking at your example data tells me that you might be looking for every tag that ends with `'ROW'`: `output = [line[0] for line in data if line[0][-3:] == 'ROW']`

Comment: Niklas, the snippet shared is a small snippet out of a huge part. ROW is the not the last tag in every case. We have to make it generic.

Comment: Thanks Niklas for your answer. For the given sample its working fine but is failing for the whole set. I am getting not only the 2nd highest but all the recs

Comment: Are you sure that your data is structured the same way as your example? It has to be a list of lists of strings. As my post answers your question, but the questions obviously does not represent your real problem, you might update your question to get answers that help you. At least provide a dataset that reproduces the problem, so I can try to fix it.